# Sparse Representation, Sparse Learning, Sparse Coding, Group Sparse Coding and Group Sparse Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, sparse

I'm really confused with these terms for the relations and difference between them:

1. Sparse Representation
2. Sparse Learning
3. Sparse Coding
4. Group Sparse Coding
5. Group Sparse Learning
6. Sparse Dictionary Learning

From some links, I think the Sparse Representation and Sparse coding are the same, aren't they? And about the other concepts, what are the differences between them?

Comment: Please, remove the [learning] tag. It is in the process of being completely removed. See discussions in the meta site.

Comment: yes, Sparse Representation and Sparse coding are the same. you can see this article: [S. Deepthi, “An Efficient Face Image Retrieval System Based on Attribute Sparse Codewords,” Int. Conf. Signal Process. Commun. Power Embed. Syst., no. 1, pp. 321–326, 2016]